# Retrieving all feature questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program to retrieve all of the links for questions that have active bounties in a specific tag. I have not yet implemented the specific tag feature, because I am stuck just try to get all of the links.

```
from re import findall
from urllib.request import urlopen


def fetch_source(url):
     return str(urlopen(url).read())


site = 'http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured'


def fetch_links(source):
    source = fetch_source(source)
    return findall("\/questions\/[0-9]*\/(?:[A-z]|\-)+", source)


print(fetch_links(site))
```

This will fetch many of the links, but it misses a lot of them because my regex only allows `[A-z]|\-` in the title. I'm not sure how to fix this though because some questions have quotation marks in the titles, and if I allow those, I will not know when the question link ends?

I'm sorry for being new to python, but I am just trying to figure stuff out.

Comment: You shouldn't be retrieving links with re.findall. Check out the Stack Exchange API instead.

Comment: Just an fyi `[A-z]` is equivalent to `[A-Z\[\\\]^_\`a-z]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using regex would become completely infeasible for getting questions by specific tag.**

You are correct that your regex is missing a lot of titles, but using findall really isn't appropriate in this situation. [Beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), is a much better tool for retrieving links, and I recommend you look into it.

In this instance, however, the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) has you covered.

For similar questions, just search(or Google) through the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) until you see the feature you're looking for, in your case [featured question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions).

Enter the parameters you want, and the API will show generate a link:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow
```

*Example for retrieving all feature Python questions*